# Read JSON and convert to C# class on specific section

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON file like this

```
{
    ...
    ...
    ...
    "ExternalApp": {
        "BaseUrl": "https://xxx.xxx.com",
        "CallbackUrl": "https://localhost/TestCallBack",
        "TokenKey": "xxxx",
        "TokenSecret": "xxxx"
    }
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

As you can see, the JSON file contains a lot of fields. One of the the setting is *ExternalApp*. I need to read this *ExternalApp* into my setting class. In .NET Core, it is very simple by using `ConfigurationBuilder`. But how to do it in legacy class (non .NET Core).

```
public class ExternalAppSetting
{
    public string BaseUrl;
    public string CallbackUrl;
    public string TokenKey;
    public string TokenSecret;
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it using [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json):

```
string json = @"{
                ""SomeProp1"": ""SomePropValue"",
                ""ExternalApp"": {
                    ""BaseUrl"": ""https://xxx.xxx.com"",
                    ""CallbackUrl"": ""https://localhost/TestCallBack"",
                    ""TokenKey"": ""xxxx"",
                    ""TokenSecret"": ""xxxx""
                },
                ""SomeProp2"": ""SomeProp2Value"",
            }";
JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);
JToken jt = o.SelectToken("ExternalApp");

ExternalAppSetting eas = jt.ToObject<ExternalAppSetting>();
```

Comment: Great! Thank you Albert!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with JSON.NET.
try this:

```
ExternalAppSetting externalAppSetting = new ExternalAppSetting();
var token = JToken.Parse(json);
var externalApp = token.SelectToken("ExternalApp");

externalAppSetting.BaseUrl = externalApp["BaseUrl"].ToString();
externalAppSetting.CallbackUrl = externalApp["CallbackUrl"].ToString();
externalAppSetting.TokenKey = externalApp["TokenKey"].ToString();
externalAppSetting.TokenSecret = externalApp["TokenSecret"].ToString();
```

where json is your json string.

Comment: I think I need to use `externalApp["BaseUrl"].ToString()`. I accepted the 2nd answer because it read directly to my class. but +1 for the answer. Thank you so much!